# Algorithm to pick sets to equal a given input of colored balls of different amounts

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

I have a specific problem and I am kind of stuck. Don't know exactly where to begin defining what it is. Is someone could just give me a nodge in the right direction or even better, tell me what kind of problem it is, that would be nice. I can of course do the hard work myself but right now I need some help figuring out what to google basically.

The problem is like this, it involves balls of different colors and amounts.

Given something along the lines of this:

**3 red balls

2 green balls

1 blue ball**

I want to find combinations of the sets below that together contain exactly the combinations of balls that are given. There can be a lot of balls of other colors and I don't care about them.

The data to choose from looks like this:

**Set 1**

`2 red
1 blue
2 yellow`

**Set 2**

`1 red
1 blue
3 purple`

**Set 3**

`1 purple
1 green`

**Set 4**

`1 red
1 green`

**Set 5**

`1 red
1 blue
2 greens
3 brown`

A possible solution would be this:

`Set 1` + `Set 3` + `Set 4` is a valid solution. It adds up to this:

`3 red
1 blue
2 green
2 yellow
1 purple`

Which contains the given specification, again, the amounts of balls contained within the solution that is of a color that is not in the given specification is not a problem. There can be multiple solutions, for example `Set 1` + `Set 5` is also a valid solution and I want to find that as well. There is no need to constraint to a specific amount of sets to be chosen, unless that is easier of course.

What kind of problem is this and what can be used to find the solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Useful would be to remove all balls of the "wrong" colors from the problem. Then you will be left only with sets containig red, blue, and green balls. After this you can remove from the problem all sets having a larger amount of balls of some color then required. Then you will be left with a finite (and rather small) number of possible sets.

Answer (score 1):

First, find every possible combination of sets that satisfy the requirement for number of red balls. For your example, these are:

$S_1 = \{1, 2\}$

$S_2 = \{1, 4\}$

$S_3 = \{1, 5\}$

$S_4 = \{2, 4, 5\}$

$S_5 = \{1, 2, 3\}$

$S_6 = \{1, 3, 4\}$

$S_7 = \{1, 4, 5\}$

$S_8 = \{1, 3, 5\}$

$S_9 = \{2, 3, 4, 5\}$

For each combination found above, find which of those combinations has the required number of green balls. These are:

$T_1 = \{1, 5\}$

$T_2 = \{1, 3, 4\}$

For each combination found above, find which of those combinations has the required number of blue balls. These are:

$U_1 = \{1, 5\}$

$U_2 = \{1, 3, 4\}$

You would need to repeat this for each color ball that you have a requirement for (here, we did this for red, green, and blue). Note the order doesn't matter. This ignores the balls of different colors that you don't have requirements for.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great observation! Really easy to understand and it helps alot, I think I can go a long way with this. It is also easy to implement. Worth mentioning also (like above) is that the number of colors that I will run this problem on in a large scale is about 500-1000 as a maximum, usually about 100. And the number of sets available could be quite huge though, possibly several thousand. But I think this is a great start and I can optimize as I go along and get to know the problem more. Thank you again!

Comment: The input is rarely more than 10 colors though, but the possible colors can be up to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the colors as:
$$
1{:}\;
\text{red},
\;\;\;
2{:}\;
\text{green},
\;\;\;
3{:}\;
\text{blue},
\;\;\;
4{:}\;
\text{yellow},
\;\;\;
5{:}\;
\text{purple},
\;\;\;
6{:}\;
\text{brown}
$$
and let $a_{i,j}$ be the number of balls of color $i$ in set $j$.

Then a solution to the problem is a $5$-tuple $x=(x_1,...,x_5)$ such that
\begin{align*}
a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+a_{1,3}x_3+a_{1,4}x_4+a_{1,5}x_5 &= 3\\
a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+a_{2,3}x_3+a_{2,4}x_4+a_{2,5}x_5 &= 2\\
a_{3,1}x_1+a_{3,2}x_2+a_{3,3}x_3+a_{3,4}x_4+a_{3,5}x_5 &= 1\\
\end{align*}
where each $x_i$ is $0$ or $1$.

If you just want to find *one* solution (if any), the problem is an instance of an integer linear programming problem.

If instead, you want find *all* solutions, then since the number of sets is small, you can simply test all $2^5=32$ candidates for $x$.

To reduce the search space,

- When a candidate $(x_1,...,x_5)$ fails one of the equations by having the $\text{LHS} > \text{RHS}$, don't bother trying any candidate $(x_1',...,x_5')$ for which
  $x_i' \ge x_i$ for all $i$.$\\[4pt]$

  When a candidate $(x_1,...,x_5)$ fails one of the equations by having the $\text{LHS} < \text{RHS}$, don't bother trying any candidate $(x_1',...,x_5')$ for which
  $x_i' \le x_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time in helping me with this! I will look at this. Worth mentioning also is that the number of colors that I will run this problem on in a large scale is about 500-1000 as a maximum, usually about 100. The number of sets to choose from could be quite huge though, possibly several thousand. But I think this is a great start and I can optimize as I go along and get to know the problem more. Thank you again!

Comment: @feggak: For the real-world problem, do you only need to find one solution?

Comment: Not really, I think I would like to provide several that fits the requerments and then be able to filter those based on other criterias not a part of this problem. I get that providing them all puts this outside the integer linear programming domain right? Does it complicate alot?

Comment: @feggak: Via integer linear programming, you can find one solution, and by maximizing various objective functions, you should be able to repeat the process so as to get a desired number, $m$ say, of distinct solutions. The computational cost is then just $m$ times the cost of getting one solution. Thus, the key question is whether getting just one solution is tractable, or intractable. For the sizes you alluded to, it's not clear.